# Is there pagination for transaction search?

Tags: soap, paypal, pagination, paypal-soap

I am trying to execute the TransactionSearchReq method using the PayPal SOAP API and i get the following warning:

ShortMessage: Search warning

LongMessage: The number of results were truncated. Please change your search parameters if you wish to see all your results.

ErrorCode: 11002

SeverityCode: Warning

It also says in the docs that "The maximum number of transactions that can be returned from a TransactionSearch API call is 100."
(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_SOAP/)

Is there some way to paginate results so that I can get more than 100 results from multiple queries?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it in Rails. This assumes you want to search from a specific point in time until now, but you could change the `end_date` to specify an end date. Note that I've added the `'paypal-sdk-merchant'` gem to my gemfile (see https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby) and followed the instructions to setup my authentication.

The two things you'll want to edit below are the `start_date` method (to set your own start date) and the `do_something(x)` method which will be whatever you want to do to each of the individual orders within your date range.

```
module PaypalTxnSearch
  def check_for_updated_orders
    begin
      @paypal_order_list = get_paypal_orders_in_range(start_date, end_date)

      @paypal_order_list.PaymentTransactions.each do |x|
        # This is where you can call a method to process each transaction
        do_something(x)
      end
      # TransactionSearch returns up to 100 of the most recent items.
    end while txn_search_result_needs_pagination?
  end

  def get_paypal_orders_in_range(start_date, end_date)
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new
    # Build Transaction Search request object
    # https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/
    @transaction_search = @api.build_transaction_search(
      StartDate: start_date,
      EndDate: end_date
    )
    # Make API call & get response
    @response = @api.transaction_search(@transaction_search)
    # Access Response
    return_response_or_errors(@response)
  end

  def start_date
    # In this example we look back 6 months, but you can change it 
    Date.today.advance(months: -6)
  end

  def end_date
    if defined?(@paypal_order_list)
      @paypal_order_list.PaymentTransactions.last.Timestamp
    else
      DateTime.now
    end
  end

  def txn_search_result_needs_pagination?
    @@paypal_order_list.Ack == 'SuccessWithWarning' &&
      @@paypal_order_list.Errors.count == 1 &&
      @@paypal_order_list.Errors[0].ErrorCode == '11002'
  end

  def return_response_or_errors(response)
    if response.success?
      response
    else
      response.Errors
    end
  end
end
```